# Which Reformed Christians deny the doctrine of common grace and why?

Tags: reformed-theology

Common grace is the doctrine that states that God has a general sense in which he gives all people, not just believers, gifts that proceed from his own graciousness. Most of these gifts concern material provision (Matthew 5:45) arts, politics, and culture (Genesis 4).

Which Reformed groups deny this? How do they explain their denial?

Comment: Why do you think that any do?

Comment: I have seen some theonomists deny it.

Comment: I bet even they have to temper their denial.  For instance, even God gives the rain to fall on the godly and ungodly alike.  If they don't call that "common grace" then they may be using a different dictionary than everybody else, that's all.